# Angular 6 Transform Animation doesn't change styles on Element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, draggable, angular-animations

**Gist**

I am creating an image slider with Angular 6, that can be moved by dragging. The position is changed via `transform: translateX(percentage)`.When the user doesn't click anymore I am animating the x-position.

**Issue(s)**

*Problem is showcased [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx8xD0EmXgw&feature=youtu.be).*

(1) The animation works but isn't changing the `transform` style of the element. (so the translateX value is wrong after the animation finished)

(2) After animating once, the dragging does not work anymore (only when destroying the animation, which results in weird behavior)

**Code**

Html:

```
<div
    class="slider"
    (mousedown)="onMouseDown($event)"
    (touchstart)="onTouchStart($event)"
    (mouseup)="onMouseUp($event)"
    (touchend)="onTouchEnd($event)"
    (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)"
    (touchmove)="onTouchMove($event)"
    (mouseleave)="onMouseLeave($event)"
    #slider
>

    <div
        class="vis-container"
        [style.transform]="translateXValue"
        [class.grabbing]="grabbing"
        [class.grab]="!grabbing"
        #container
    >
        <div
            class="item"
            *ngFor="let i of images; let j = index"
            [style.left]="j * 100 + '%'"
        >
            <img
                dyImagePositioning
                src="{{i}}"
            >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>{{translateXValue}}</div>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
images: string[] = [
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533147722845-4078740ae714?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=c8e866ca41f36ad560c435c1bb51e0fd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80',
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504415724575-56cef5e3da72?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=89c39a767a764693bcc2e2c2ecad59ce&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80',
        'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/drakery-4/product-files/5b5c8d96823eba53e45ba5ac/5b5c8d9a823eba53e45ba5ad-normal.webp',
    ];

    grabbing: boolean = false;
    startX: number;
    startXPerc: number;
    translateX: number = 0;
    animationDurance: number = 300;

    @ViewChild('slider') slider;
    @ViewChild('container') container;

    constructor(
        private builder: AnimationBuilder,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void { }

    start(pageX: number): void {
        this.grabbing = true;
        this.startX = pageX - this.slider.nativeElement.offsetLeft;
        this.startXPerc = this.translateX;
    }
    onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent): void {
        this.start(event.pageX);
    }
    onTouchStart(event: TouchEvent): void {
        this.start(event.changedTouches[0].pageX);
    }

    end(): void {
        this.grabbing = false;
        const endX = Math.round(this.translateX / 100) * 100;
        const animationFactory = this.builder.build(this.translate(
            this.translateX,
            endX,
        ));
        const animationPlayer: AnimationPlayer = animationFactory.create(this.container.nativeElement);
        animationPlayer.play();
        // Destroying the animation makes it able
        // to drag again, but results in weird behaviour
        /* animationPlayer.onDone(() => {
            animationPlayer.destroy();
        }) */
    }
    onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent): void {
        this.end();
    }
    onTouchEnd(event: TouchEvent): void {
        this.end();
    }

    move(pageX: number): void {
        if (!this.grabbing) return;
        event.preventDefault();
        const x = pageX - this.slider.nativeElement.offsetLeft;
        const diff = this.startX - x;
        const diffPerc = 100 * diff / this.slider.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
        this.translateX = this.startXPerc - diffPerc;
    }
    onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
        this.move(event.pageX);
    }
    onTouchMove(event: TouchEvent): void {
        this.move(event.changedTouches[0].pageX);
    }

    onMouseLeave(event: MouseEvent): void {
        if (!this.grabbing) return;
        this.grabbing = false;
        this.end();
    }

    get translateXValue(): string {
        return `translateX(${this.translateX}%)`
    }

    private translate(startX: number, endX: number): AnimationMetadata[] {
        return [
            style({ transform: `translateX(${startX}%)` }),
            animate(`${this.animationDurance}ms ease-out`, style({ transform: `translateX(${endX}%)` })),
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I would dump the angular animation and simply use a css animation instead.
So in your case it would something like this:

```
.slider
    ...
    transition-duration: 500ms
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. Destroying the animation only is not enough since the style property is reset to its state before the animation and thus has undesired behavior. In the `onDone` callback you should, before destroying the animation, set the new style property to the element:

```
// ...

animation.onDone(() => {
  this.container.nativeElement.style.transform = this.translate(
    this.translateX,
    endX,
  );
  animation.destroy();
});
```